# Delphi Window on Top of all other apps while main window below

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have an application composed of one main window and a popup I want to be on top of all other applications. Let's call "Window A" to the main window, "Window B" to the on-top popup and "Window C" to another application's window.

I'm setting Window B on top using this code:

```
    SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                 SWP_NoMove or SWP_NoSize);
```

This works as expected, I can open another application (Window C) and Window B keeps on top. But if I click on its window title the "Window A" brings to front, on top of "Window C". Is there a way to prevent the main window (Window A) to brint to front when clicking any part of Window B?.

Comment: Is Window A owned by Window B?

Comment: Override CreateParams of B to set WndParent = 0. Asked many times here. BTW, you can use fsStayOnTop as FormStyle.

Comment: Obviously you won't be able to be on top of all other windows. You'll lose out to other windows that want to do the same. Likely A is the owner of B, in the Win32 sense. Do what Sertac says to make B be unowned.

Comment: If it's been asked many times here, @Sertac, then can you please vote to close this as a duplicate instead of giving the answer in a comment?

Comment: It's impossible to guarantee 100%, because there are bound to be other applications which will fight with yours for that position, who will come out on top. Kinda like these elections...

Comment: @Rob - I might be wrong about that, I failed to locate an exact duplicate.

Comment: @JerryDodge: The OP isn't concerned about their topmost window not being topmost under certain circumstances. They are asking, why the owner (A) of that window (B) comes to the front, when the topmost window (B) is activated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have "Window B" always on top, you can set its `FormStyle` property to `fsStayOnTop`, you don't need to call `SetWindowPos`. Override `CreateParams` to have it *unowned* by any window, so that it won't bring along its owner to the front when it is activated.

```
type
  TWindowB = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

procedure TWindowB.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.WndParent := 0;
end;

procedure TWindowB.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
end;
```

For a normal window (e.g. `BorderStyle` = `bsSizeable`), you'll have a taskbar button and Alt+Tab icon for "Window B". This is normal, as the window does not depend on any other window for activation now, it should have means to activate it. To avoid that you can use `bsToolWindow` or `bsSizeToolWin` as `BorderStyle`, or the hidden Application window as window owner by setting `Application.Handle` to `Params.WndParent`.

Note that a topmost window does not have any priority over other possible topmost windows, any one of them might be brought to front.